# How to fuzzy match by words (not letters) in R?

Tags: r, string-matching, stringr, fuzzyjoin

I need to merge two datasets based on columns that contain names that don't exaclty match, sometimes because one of the columns has a missing name with respect to the other. For example, in one column I have `"Martín Gallardo"` and in the other I have `"Martín Ricardo Gallardo"`. Another problem is that in some first and last name appear reversed, like `"Martín Gallardo"` in one and `"Gallardo Martín"` in the other. How can I match this using R? My first thought was to use `str_split` in both  and assign each on one set to the one that matches more elements from the other set, but I'm not sure how to code this.

Thank you.

Edit: data looks something like this

```r
A <- tibble(email=c("martingallardo23@gmail.com","raulgimenez@gmail.com"), 
name=c("martin", "raul"), last_name=c("gallardo","gimenez"), 
full_name=c("martin gallardo", "raul gimenez"))
A
#  A tibble: 2 x 4
#   email                      name   last_name full_name
#   <chr>                      <chr>  <chr>     <chr>          
# 1 martingallardo23@gmail.com martin gallardo  martin gallardo
# 2 raulgimenez@gmail.com      raul   gimenez   raul gimenez   

B <- tibble(email=c("martingallardo@gmail.com", "raulgimenez2@gmail.com"), 
name=c("martin ricardo", "gimenez"), last_name=c("gallardo", "raul"), 
full_name=c("martin ricardo gallardo", "gimenez raul"), other_data=c("A", "B"))
B
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#   email                    name           last_name full_name              other_data
#   <chr>                    <chr>          <chr>     <chr>                   <chr>     
# 1 martingallardo@gmail.com martin ricardo gallardo  martin ricardo gallardo A         
# 2 raulgimenez2@gmail.com   gimenez        raul      gimenez raul            B
```

Comment: Could you please share a reproducible piece of your data? So that others can help you more efficiently.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR There I added an example of the data, does that work? I want to match A to B using full_name. There is also an email available but does not always match.

Comment: @MartinGallardo you then want to merge 2 data sets? I mean based on those rows that match.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Yes, exactly.

Comment: @PKumar I will try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tidyverse way to do the join. It basically finds full_name from B that has the highest number of common words with A.
library(tidyverse)

```
A1 <- tibble(
  nombre_completo = c("martin gallardo", "raul gimenez")
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    id_A = row_number()
  )

B1 <- tibble(
  nombre_completo=c("martin ricardo gallardo", "gimenez raul"),
  other_data=c("A", "B")
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    id_B = row_number()
  )


A2 <- A1 %>%
  mutate(
    name_words = str_split(nombre_completo, pattern = " ")
  ) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(name_words))

B2 <- B1 %>%
  mutate(
    name_words = str_split(nombre_completo, pattern = " ")
  ) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(name_words)) %>%
  select(name_words, id_B )


left_join(A2, B2, by = "name_words") %>%
  group_by(nombre_completo, id_A, id_B) %>%
  count() %>% ungroup() %>%
  group_by(nombre_completo, id_A) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = n) %>%
  select("nombre_completo_A" = nombre_completo, id_A, id_B) %>%
  left_join(B1, by = "id_B")
```

Comment: This is very good, thank you so much. Is there a way to get only the best fit in the end? I'm getting one nombre_completo_A matched to several from nombre_completo, all of those that share at least one word. Again, thank you!

Comment: Actually I think I got it. Thank you!

Comment: You’re welcome. Feel free to upvote/mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Nice idea, you certainly deserve an upvote dear @Jakub.Novotny.

Answer (score 1):

In order for these two data sets to be matched I first created a column `nombre_completo2` in a restructured form of data set `A` based on how `nombre_completo` in data set `A` partially match the same column in data set `B`. Then I merged the two data sets so that the additional columns in data set `B` is added to the restructured form of `A`. This is how I interpreted your desired output in the first place so I hope it will be useful to you:

```
A <- tibble(email=c("martingallardo23@gmail.com","raulgimenez@gmail.com"), 
            name=c("martin", "raul"), last_name=c("gallardo","gimenez"), 
            nombre_completo=c("martin gallardo", "raul gimenez"))


B <- tibble(email=c("martingallardo@gmail.com", "raulgimenez2@gmail.com"), 
            name=c("martin ricardo", "gimenez"), last_name=c("gallardo", "raul"), 
            nombre_completo=c("martin ricardo gallardo", "gimenez raul"), 
            other_data=c("A", "B"))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

A %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(nombre_completo2 = map_chr(nombre_completo, 
                                ~ B$nombre_completo
                                [str_detect(B$nombre_completo, str_sub(.x, 1L, 4L))])) %>%
  inner_join(B, by = c("nombre_completo2" = "nombre_completo")) %>%
  select(!ends_with(".y")) %>%
  rename_with(~ str_replace(., ".x", ""), ends_with(".x"))


# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Rowwise: 
  email                      name   last_name nombre_completo nombre_completo2       other_data
  <chr>                      <chr>  <chr>     <chr>           <chr>                  <chr>     
1 martingallardo23@gmail.com martin gallardo  martin gallardo martin ricardo gallar~ A         
2 raulgimenez@gmail.com      raul   gimenez   raul gimenez    gimenez raul           B
```

Comment: This is also very useful. Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure, I would have also liked to test it on a larger data set. Please feel free to upvote or select every answer which meets your requirements. Best wishes.